# Counting transactions considering unique values and dates with formula

Tags: excel

I am attempting to retrieve the count of unique transactions through Excel with the below formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('CA SAP'!$E:$E,Synthèse!A14,'CA SAP'!$P:$P,">="&Synthèse!D4,'CA SAP'!$P:$P,"<="&Synthèse!E4,'CA SAP'!$N:$N,">0")
```

Synthèse! A14 is the name of the website
Synthèse! D4 & Synthèse! E4 are both dates
CA SAP'!$N:$N,">0" is for the transaction amount.

There is a column CA SAP'!$T:$T where I am trying to retrieve the distinct values as well I am trying to count the distinct transactions given a time period for a transaction above 0.

I have written the below formula but I am unable to get any correct results with it, the above formula works well however it includes duplicate values from CA SAP'!$T:$T

```
=COUNTIFS('CA SAP'!$E:$E,Synthèse!A11,'CA SAP'!$P:$P,">="&Synthèse!D4,'CA SAP'!$P:$P,"<="&Synthèse!E4,'CA SAP'!$T:$T,"="&UNIQUE('CA SAP'!$T:$T),'CA SAP'!$N:$N,">""0")
```

I have added a picture of the data below.

[image]

Comment: What version of excel are you using? If you're on Office365 you could use the `=UNIQUE()` formula to get distinct values, then put a count outside of that?

Comment: I am using the most up to date excel, i understand your point however i have to include multiple conditions as well as the count, such as the date and the column N being above 0

Comment: You already opened a question about this: Please, **do not** duplicate questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71154388/counting-transactions-considering-unique-values-and-dates-with-formula

Comment: Use `UNIQUE()` then `COUNTA()` to count unique records.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in my formula

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting transactions considering unique values and dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71139132/counting-transactions-considering-unique-values-and-dates)

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER('CA SAP'!$T:$T, ('CA SAP'!$E:$E=Synthèse!A14)*('CA SAP'!$P:$P >= Synthèse!D4)*('CA SAP'!$P:$P <= Synthèse!E4)*('CA SAP'!$N:$N > 0))))
```

The `FILTER()` formula applies the criteria to the transactions, the `UNIQUE()` removes duplicates and then `COUNTA` gives the count of the result.

See [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function#:%7E:text=More%20than%20one%20criteria) for a guide to FILTER function with multiple criteria.